# Python addon in VScode not working after downloading github extensions

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code

I get an error every time that says "you don't have an extension for debugging Python", even though I do. It seems like the Python extension is not working, telling me the error "Activating extension 'ms-python.python' failed: Attempt to insert a duplicate controller with ID "python-tests"." I recently got the github repository addon as well as codespace and related items, do you think this has to do with anything?

Comment: you can temporarily disable the new extensions and see if python works again

Comment: Could you try to disable all the extensions and then only enable the `Python` extension? If it still not work could you try to install the early version of the `Python` extension?

Comment: Both didn't work, I'm not sure why.